# Make paragraph with special character or programming source code?

Tags: characters

Is there an easy way to type a programming command line or paragraph with special character ?

example this:

```
@Test(name = "Login", urlPatterns = { "/login" })
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
// Test URL
private static final String TEST_TEST_TEST = "https://<test DFHB>:<test>";
// TEST URL
```

in LaTex I type this on this:

```
{@}Test(name = {"Login"}, urlPatterns = {\{} "/login" {\}})\newline
public class Login extends HttpServlet {\{}\newline
{/}{/} Test URL\newline
 private static final String TEST{\_}SERVICE{\_}URL {=} "https{:}{/}{/}<test DFHB>:<test>"{;}\newline
 {/}{/} TEST URL
```

Comment: If I understand what you want correctly (not sure I do),`\begin{verbatim} ... \end{vebatim}` would be the built in environment for this, but also check out [fancyvrb](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb?lang=en) or [minted](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_Highlighting_with_minted) for fancier output for source code.

Comment: And since it's missing from @frabjous list of packages with fancier outputt, you might also take a look at [`listings`](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings).